# Update int column in table with unique incrementing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to populate any rows missing a value in their `InterfaceID (INT)` column with a unique value per row.

I'm trying to do this query:

```
UPDATE prices SET interfaceID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(interfaceID),0) + 1 FROM prices) 
       WHERE interfaceID IS null
```

I was hoping the the `(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(interfaceID),0) + 1 FROM prices)` would be evaluated for every row, but its only done once and so all my affected rows are getting the same value instead of different values.

Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
declare @i int  = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(interfaceID),0) + 1 FROM prices)


update prices
set interfaceID  = @i , @i = @i + 1
where interfaceID is null
```

should do the work

Comment: check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/28/sql-auto-increment.aspx/) too, hope helps someone.

Comment: Add parentheses around `(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(interfaceID),0) + 1 FROM prices)`

Comment: i was using a CURSOR to perform some task which took 15 minutes to process 80000 records. i just used this way and now that task take only 4 seconds. saved my life. thanks.

Comment: How come you have +1 on both the `SELECT` and the `SET`? Shouldn't it just be on one of them?

Comment: Man I was doing a while loop with @i+1 then an update statement until there were none left. I let this run over night and it had done about 600,000 records ran this and it was done in 1 minute 40 seconds to do 700,000 records

Comment: this solution updates 8 records by 8 records, i mean each time new set is done for 8 data, then @i =@i +1 processed, i dont know why but does not work for me

Comment: `ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 673
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_210100", line 659
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1855`

Answer (score 23):

```
DECLARE @IncrementValue int
SET @IncrementValue = 0 
UPDATE Samples SET qty = @IncrementValue,@IncrementValue=@IncrementValue+1
```

Answer (score 13):

simple query would be, just set a variable to some number you want.
then update the column you need by incrementing 1 from that number. for all the rows it'll update each row id by incrementing 1

```
SET @a  = 50000835 ;  
UPDATE `civicrm_contact` SET external_identifier = @a:=@a+1 
WHERE external_identifier IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have a primary key for this table (you should have), as well as using a CTE or a WITH, it is also possible to use an update with a self-join to the same table:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.interfaceId = b.sequence
FROM prices a
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY b.priceId ) + ( SELECT MAX( interfaceId ) + 1 FROM prices ) AS sequence, b.priceId
   FROM prices b
   WHERE b.interfaceId IS NULL
) b ON b.priceId = a.priceId
```

I have assumed that the primary key is price-id.

The derived table, alias b, is used to generated the sequence via the ROW_NUMBER() function together with the primary key column(s). For each row where the column interface-id is NULL, this will generate a row with a unique sequence value together with the primary key value.

It is possible to order the sequence in some other order rather than the primary key.

The sequence is offset by the current MAX interface-id + 1 via a sub-query. The MAX() function ignores NULL values.

The WHERE clause limits the update to those rows that are NULL.

The derived table is then joined to the same table, alias a, joining on the primary key column(s) with the column to be updated set to the generated sequence.

Answer (score 4):

For Postgres

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD field_name serial PRIMARY KEY
```

REFERENCE: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm

Answer (score 2):

In oracle-based products you may use the following statement:

```
update table set interfaceID=RowNum where condition;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
    select p.*,
           (coalesce(max(interfaceid) over (), 0) +
            row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
           ) as newInterfaceId
    from prices
   )
update p
    set interfaceId = newInterfaceId
    where interfaceId is NULL
```

This doesn't quite make them consecutive, but it does assign new higher ids.  To make them consecutive, try this:

```
with toupdate as (
    select p.*,
           (coalesce(max(interfaceid) over (), 0) +
            row_number() over (partition by interfaceId order by (select NULL))
           ) as newInterfaceId
    from prices
   )
update p
    set interfaceId = newInterfaceId
    where interfaceId is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

My table has 500 million records. The below code worked for me.

```sql
-- update rows using a CTE - Ervin Steckl 

;WITH a AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn, id
FROM accounts2
) 
UPDATE a SET id=rn
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1467/populate-a-sql-server-column-with-a-sequential-number-not-using-an-identity/

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

````sql
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = @counter, @counter = @counter + 1```
````