# Need to auto increment string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Consider the table in SQL Server 2012

```
789-0000000
```

The above number will be consider as a string in SQL Server 2012, but whenever I update the record I need increment to 1.

For example:

- When I update the record 1 it should increment to `789-0000001`
- When I update the record 2 it should increment to `789-0000002`

Finally increment should done only 789-**0000000**

Comment: use combination of auto increment with one extra prefix column value "789" or just put it constant in your code.

Comment: Why not just have a normal incrementing number and concatenate it to the string 789- when you want to output/display it?

Comment: please provide example code since i am beginner @JaydeepPandya

Comment: when i store 0000 as sql server i takes as 0 @Dijkgraaf

Comment: Use padding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CompanyID AS '789-' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 7) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `dbo.YourTable` without specifying values for `ID` or `CompanyID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CompanyID` will contain values like `789-0000001`, `789-0000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @base int = 0

UPDATE TableX

SET 
    TableX.Value = 'Prefix' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(@base AS nvarchar),7),
    @base = @base + 1

FROM
    TableX
```

Comment: code only responses are discouraged. Please add some explanation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

you can [split](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx) the string
e.g.:

```
SELECT Item
FROM dbo.SplitString('Apple,Mango,Banana,Guava', ',')
```

then [cast](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/) it 
e.g.:

```
SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) FROM Table
```

then [manually increment](http://ask.metafilter.com/161275/How-to-manually-increment-an-integer-value-in-a-SQL-Server-2005-database-table) it

e.g.:

```
DECLARE max_id INT
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM source_table)

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
SELECT columns, to, copy
FROM source_table

OPEN cursor_name

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name
INTO @columns, @to, @cop
```

at [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629382/update-int-column-in-table-with-unique-incrementing-values)
e.g.:

```
declare @i int  = SELECT ISNULL(MAX(interfaceID),0) + 1 FROM prices

update prices
set interfaceID  = @i , @i = @i + 1
where interfaceID is null
```

you can understand how complicate this is and why
the solution using a constant to store that prefix is right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @str varchar(max) = '789-0000000'

Select 
   SUBSTRING ( @str ,0 ,CHARINDEX ( '-' ,@str  ))
   +'-'
   +
   (SUBSTRING ( @str ,(CHARINDEX ( '-' ,@str)+1) ,(7-LEN(CAST(SUBSTRING ( @str ,CHARINDEX ( '-' ,@str)+1,LEN(@str)) as int))
              )
    )+
   CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING ( @str ,CHARINDEX ( '-' ,@str)+1,LEN(@str)) as int)+1 as varchar))
```

When `@str='789-0001947'`

Output `@str= 789-0001948`

You can write a update trigger on the table with above logic.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks :)  yeah i started learning how to answer in StackOverflow.