# How do I create a table with multiple auto incrementing values?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to have an autoincrementing string in my BigQuery table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969020/need-to-auto-increment-string-in-sql-server-2012) seems like a good way of doing it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    CompanyID AS '789-' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 7) PERSISTED,
    .... your other columns here....
)
```

However I actually want a single column based on multiple such counts with different prefixes.

So in the example a new record comes in and gets the label 789-00056. For my data if I have an a-record I want the label to be a-[running count of a's + 1], for b: b-[running count of b's + 1].

The data would look like this:

| record type | label |
| --- | --- |
| a | a-1 |
| a | a-2 |
| b | b-1 |
| a | a-3 |

Comment: Bigquery isn't really designed to be a transactional database like this.  Can you explain what the underlying need is?  Does it need to be deterministic, or just a number for a specific query? If the later, you can just use row_number().

Comment: Thanks Mike. It is just  keeping a tally count of each type of record. Can you explain what you mean by ' deterministic, or just a number for a specific query?' please?

Comment: Meaning to you need that number to be the same for that row forever, or are you just using it for counting purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
 SELECT field1, field2 ,field3, 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field3 ASC) AS my_label

 FROM table
```