# How can I update all rows in Postgresql from 1 to N, where N number of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Find this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629639/947111 but it's for sqlserver while I need it for Postgresql.

For example my `table` has the following structure:

```
id|title|slot_id
----------------
1 |    1|     1
2 |    2|     1
3 |    3|     1
4 |    1|     2
5 |    2|     2
```

When I delete row from the middle of set (set defined by `slot_id`), for example 1,2,3 where `slot_id` = 1 and row with title = 2 was removed I need to perform renaming so it won't 1,3 but 1,2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't provide sufficient information about your table structure, so you need to adjust the following query yourself to your table and column names:

```
update the_table
  set the_column_to_update = t.rn
from (
  select the_primary_key_column, 
         row_number() over (order by the_primary_key_column) as rn
  from x
) t 
where t.the_primary_key_column = x.the_primary_key_column;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in "[Update int column in table with unique incrementing values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629639/947111)" is referring to adding an **automatically incremented id** in a table after having defined the table.

In SQL Server this is called an `IDENTITY` column while in PostgreSQL it is called a `SERIAL` column.

You can find a similar solution (if that is what you need) in:
[Adding 'serial' to existing column in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490014/adding-serial-to-existing-column-in-postgres).

That is if you want to update a column with a value starting from 1 up to N to serve as a unique id for each row of your table.

If you define the table from the beginning as such then you can set one column as `SERIAL` as in the following article: [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)